# MySQL find and replace XXX if it's between YYY and ZZZ

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I'm working on a WordPress-based project and I need to batch edit the posts from the database.

At the moment I have cells, where the content is `Text <pre> Text\r\nText\r\nText </pre>`

What I need to do is find all the `\r\n` strings and replace them with `\r\n\r\n`. So far I have this:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
SET `field_name` = replace(field_name, '\r\n', '\r\n\r\n\')
```

The issue is, there is also `\r\n\` text outside the `<pre>` tags, which I don't want to affect. That's why I need to do something like `find (start: '<pre>' end: '</pre>')` before calling the replace. I just have no idea how to do this in MySQL.

When web searching, I found some stuff about regex but I have no idea how that works.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "regex repace" in MySQL. You will need a PHP script to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have the regexp replace functionality. I'd say you have two options - either create an user defined function that will do this kind of replacement, or, if you can't / don't know how to, you have to use a script/program written in a different language. It may be e.g. a PHP script that will connect to the db and do the desired replacement. Another way would be to dump the table containing your posts to a file, use sed or something similar and import the data once again.

Using sed would probably take less time than PHP and the syntax is fairly easy to learn.

Whatever you choose remember it's always a good idea to make a backup before.